# Оптимизация при создании исполняемого файла через pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, библиотеки, exe, pyinstaller

Я создал одну програмку на python и хочу скомпилировать ее в exe-файл через pyinstaller. Компиляция проходит успешно, но размер исполняемого файла слишком велик (в моем случае - 50 мегабайт). Хотелось бы сократить до 20, максимум.

И я подумал, что такой размер происходит из-за того, что я импортирую много библиотек, которые много весят.

Тогда я немного сократил импортирование. К примеру, `import cv2` заменил на `from cv2 import VideoCapture, imwrite, CAP_DSHOW`. И так далее.

Вот я снова скомпили файл, и... та-дам! Размер не изменился не на байт!

А очень хотелось бы, чтобы изменился.

Помогите, пожалуйста, как можно сократить размер исполняемого файла, созданого через pyinstaller? Добавить что-то в `.spec` файл? Изменить что-то в самом коде?

Comment: Если собираете в один exe файл, то в него крепятся все динамические библиотеки, та же  библиотека opencv, например, которая изначально компилируется из кода на С++. Значительно уменьшить размер получится разве что убрав эту библиотеку (и другие библиотеки) совсем (что вряд ли вас устроит). Единственно, проверьте что exe у вас пакуется с помощью upx (должно быть где-то в настройках сборки), это может дать некоторый выигрыш в размере.

Comment: Я пробовал upx, но только не во время компиляции, а уже с готовым файлом. Но там пара мегабайт убирается и все. А как можно использовать upx в pyinstaller?

Comment: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/usage.html#using-upx Вкратце - нужно передать путь к папке upx через параметр `--upx-dir`. Также скорее всего в spec файле можно прописать.